# SQL updating data with duplicate information

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So i've been working on this query for awhile and for some reason whenever i run it, it tries to update certain fields that are already equal in both tables. For example take these two tables:

> AlldataTable
>   first__last__age__number
>   K____    D  **__**  17____    7
>   K____    D  **__**  15____    7
>   X____ X___ 12 ____21
>
> NewDataTable
>   first__last__age__number
>   K____    D  **__**  17____    7
>   K____    D  **__**  15____    7
>   X____ X___ 13 ____22

so the goal here is to have the age field for x x update to 13 and the number field to update to 22 when the query is executed. But when i execute the code it would say for example that it is going to update all three entries when just the third should be.

```
UPDATE AllDataTable
LEFT JOIN NewDataTable ON (AllDataTable.first = NewDataTable.first)
    AND (AllDataTable.last = NewDataTable.last)

SET AllDataTable.age = NewDataTable.age
    ,AllDataTable.number = NewDataTable.number
WHERE (
        AllDataTable.age <> NewDataTable.age
        OR AllDataTable.number <> NewDataTable.number
        )
    AND AllDataTable.first = NewDataTable.first
    AND AllDataTable.last = NewDataTable.last;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your duplicated values in `first` and `last`. The database is seeing three hits on the WHERE clause:

- Alldata first row against NewData second row.
- Alldata second row against NewData first row.
- Alldata third row against NewData third row.

This gives the appearance of only one row changing, but you get an affected row count of three because the first and second rows actually swap all their contents in addition to the third row being updated.

Comment: so i guess then my question is how do i change the query so it does not swap the contents of the duplicated rows thus giving me a row count equivalent to only the number of rows that need updating

Comment: No, wrong idea. The problem is that `first` and `last` are your only actual key values, so you have no real way of distinguishing between the first and second rows in your `Alldata` table. It's an incorrect database design; your rows are not uniquely identified, so the very idea of updating a row in place is meaningless.

Comment: The thing your code is actually saying is: "If your name is K.D. and your age is not 17, then I'm saying you're 17 now. At the same time, if your name is K.D. and your age is not 15, I'm saying you're 15 now." And you've got two people named K.D., ages 15 and 17. The 15-year-old just became 17 and the 17-year-old just became 15. That makes no sense because you're not identifying the people you actually want to change. The trouble with programming is that there is no good way to ask for something that makes no sense!